# Model choice - between subject experiment with serial dependence across time

Tags: anova, mixed-model, independence, random-allocation

I have done a teaching experiment where I have randomly assigned students to four different teaching style treatments for a whole semester. I have then used quizzes on a weekly basis to assess learning outcome and also a final exam that covered the whole 5 week semester.

I am now trying to figure out how to best analyze the data. Traditionally I have always done simple experiments using ANOVA but since there is serial dependence between the quizzes and the final exam and the quizzes as well I was wondering if I should be using a mixed model approach.

My hesitation is that the quizzes are not covering the same content each week so not sure if this is a repeated measure per se?
Same issue with the final exam since it covers 5 weeks’ worth of content. Technically there is serial dependence with the quiz results and not just a pure treatment effect.

I have attached an image showing the data structure. Would be very appreciative of some input as most of the existing guidance I have found has been with respect to repeated measures that are measuring exactly the same thing rather than something similar.

[image: Data Structure]

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have any missing data, then the main use of a repeated measures model would be to estimate a treatment effect that is assumed to be identical across tests  (perhaps unlikely?). If you want to separately consider each test,  you could just do an ANOVA/ANCOVA/etc.

Once you have missing data, a repeated measures model becomes attractive even for estimating a separate treatment effect at each test by having terns for treatment, test and treatment by test in the model (plus e.g. pre-course score and test by pre-course score interaction, if available). If you just analyzed available scores for each test, you make huge assumptions and could get really odd effects (e.g. you might find that the teaching technique of publically shaming the worst students is "best", because most of the worst quit the course...).

A mixed effects model answers (or tries to under some reasonable assumptions) the question of "If all students had stayed in the course what would their scores have been throughout?" and takes into account to what extent early tests correlate with later (possibly missing) tests under a missing at random (MAR) assumption. MAR means that drop-out can depend on the already observed test scores of a student, but e.g. there should not be a mechanism like a non observed pre-test before each test that causes people to drop-out, or like an ability to strike a test off the record of you do not like the result (and try again next term - although that would be fine, as long as you still get that score anyway for your research purposes). Even more sophisticated imputation of missing data is of course possible and can be tailored to exactly what question you wish to answer.

In terms of assumed covariance matrix, I  would use an unstructured one, rather than e.g. an AR(1) or a simple student random effect, which is the same as a compound symmetric covariance matrix (simple covariance structures tend to induce strong assumptions that are usually badly wrong and can have big effects).

You did not say exactly how people were allocated to teaching methods. If it was randomization of individual students to courses, the above is it,  otherwise (e.g. self selection to courses and random assignment of treatment to the course groups) further difficulties come in and must be accounted for to avoid misleading results.